# Injection Token Provider definition for Lazy Loaded Module not working

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-ngrx-data

I have defined a module for data access in my angular application and I am using NgRx/Data.

The Module hierarchy looks like this:

AppModule

- Customer-Module (LazyLoaded) -> Imports Customer-Data-Module

Within my Customer-Data-Module I have set the providers array for the pluralName configuration like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers:[
    { provide: PLURAL_NAMES_TOKEN, multi: true, useValue: entityConfig.pluralNames, },
  ] 
})
export class CustomerDataModule {
  constructor(private eds: EntityDefinitionService, pluralizer: Pluralizer) {    
    eds.registerMetadataMap(entityConfig.entityMetadata);
  }
}
```

I found an example for this [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-ngrx-data/blob/master/docs/entity-metadata.md) and it works if I put the provider definition into my AppModule (but nowhere else).

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @IslombekHasanov from my research it looks like this provider setup with lazy loaded modules is not possible in Angular.